# Kubernetes networking, can't reach service nodePort from another network

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Raspberry pi cluster which is built using kubeadm.

```
master : 10.42.0.159
worker node : 10.42.0.192
```

I want to expose a pod which is running on the worker node, using a service of type=nodeport with the nodePort 30101. Now I can do `curl 10.42.0.159:30101` or `curl 10.42.0.192:30101` on both master and worker node. But when I try to curl the same on other machines sitting on a different network, such as `10.10.14.67`, it fails.

I have set the iptables of both master and worker to accept any forward. My question is how to access the pod using NodeID:Nodeport from a different network?

Answer (score 0):

For access from a different network, you must have a route between your networks.  When you have the route, you will have the possibility to request your nodes. You need to configure it on your router.